# Serialise object to JSON with array - preparing data for bar Flot Chart

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am preparing data for FlotChart and I am struggling with array conversion under `data`. This shall not include variable names.

Input data format reference:
[Data format reference](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)

The expected result in JSON:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Series 1",
    "color": "#0077ff",
    "data": [
      [ "a", 1 ],
      [ "b", 2 ],
      [ "c", 3 ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Series 2",
    "color": "#ffccaa",
    "data": [
      [ "aa", 11 ],
      [ "bb", 22 ],
      [ "cc", 33 ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Code I am using to create JSON output. Simplified for clearness:

```
Public Class DataSeries
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property color As String
    Public Property data As List(Of DataSet)
End Class

Public Class DataSet
    Public Property x As String
    Public Property y As Decimal
End Class

Public Sub TestChart()

    Dim DataForJSON As New List(Of DataSeries)
    Dim MyDataSeries = As DataSeries

    MyDataSeries = New DataSeries
    MyDataSeries.label = "Series 1"
    MyDataSeries.color = "#0077ff"
    MyDataSeries.data = New List(Of DataSet)
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "a", .y = 1})
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "b", .y = 2})
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "c", .y = 3})
    MyDataSeries.Add(WykresBarDataSet)
    DataForJSON.Add(MyDataSeries)

    MyDataSeries = New DataSeries
    MyDataSeries.label = "Series 2"
    MyDataSeries.color = "#ffccaa"
    MyDataSeries.data = New List(Of DataSet)
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "aa", .y = 11})
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "bb", .y = 22})
    WykresBarDataSet.data.Add(New DataSet() With {.x = "cc", .y = 32})
    MyDataSeries.Add(WykresBarDataSet)
    DataForJSON.Add(MyDataSeries)

    Dim JSON_txt As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataForJSON)

End Sub
```

Comment: The inside of data array is wrong, it's supposed to be "data": [{"a", 1},{"b", 2},{"c", 3},...]

Comment: @CruleD Samle JSON comes from working example (when data hardcoded). Will try to test it, but this still does not tell me how to generate such JSON from my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
Dim DataForJSON As New List(Of DataSeries)

Dim MyDataSeries As New DataSeries With {
    .label = "Series 1",
    .color = "#0077ff",
    .data = New List(Of DataSet)
}
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "a", .y = 1})
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "b", .y = 2})
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "c", .y = 3})
DataForJSON.Add(MyDataSeries)

MyDataSeries = New DataSeries With {
    .label = "Series 2",
    .color = "#ffccaa",
    .data = New List(Of DataSet)
}
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "aa", .y = 11})
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "bb", .y = 22})
MyDataSeries.data.Add(New DataSet With {.x = "cc", .y = 32})
DataForJSON.Add(MyDataSeries)

Dim JSON_txt As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataForJSON)
```

Output:

```
[
   {"label":"Series 1",
    "color":"#0077ff",
    "data":[
         {"x":"a", "y":1.0},
         {"x":"b", "y":2.0},
         {"x":"c", "y":3.0}
           ]
   },
   {"label":"Series 2",
    "color":"#ffccaa",
    "data":[
         {"x":"aa", "y":11.0},
         {"x":"bb", "y":22.0},
         {"x":"cc", "y":32.0}
           ]
   }
]
```

Which is the proper output.

---

Or if you want the

```
 "data": [
      [ "aa", 11 ],
      [ "bb", 22 ],
      [ "cc", 33 ]
```

Then do it like this:

```
   Public Class DataSeries
        Public Property label As String
        Public Property color As String
        Public Property data As List(Of List(Of Object))
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim DataForJSON As New List(Of DataSeries)

        Dim MyDataSeries As New DataSeries With {
            .label = "Series 1",
            .color = "#0077ff",
            .data = List(Of List(Of Object))
        }
        MyDataSeries.data.Add(New List(Of Object)({"aa", 11}))
        MyDataSeries.data.Add(New List(Of Object)({"bb", 22}))
        MyDataSeries.data.Add(New List(Of Object)({"cc", 32}))
        DataForJSON.Add(MyDataSeries)

        Dim JSON_txt As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataForJSON)

    End Sub
```

Output:

```
[
   {"label":"Series 1",
    "color":"#0077ff",
    "data":[
         ["aa", 11],
         ["bb", 22],
         ["cc", 32]
           ]
   }
]
```

Comment: The JSON provided comes from working however static example. I am trying to create it dynamically. Apart from the array formatting issue, how to get rid of x and y variable name?

Comment: Don't make a property, property is the name, value of the property is the value. To get an array inside and array, you can add list to a list.

Comment: I have updated the question with link to data format reference of Flot Charts.

Comment: I also added the second part.

Comment: Almost there. The only problem now is that numbers shall be numbers not strings `[ "aa", 11 ]` instead of `[ "aa", "11" ]`. The chart library uses those numbers to make calculations and properly display on y axis. So a list of list of a string and decimal pair.

Comment: Hmm yeah, fixed it now.

Comment: Get an error `C36915 Cannot infer an element type because more than one type is possible. Specifying the type of the array might correct this error.` at `MyDataSeries.data.Add({"aa", 11})`

Comment: Works fine for me, not sure why would you get an error if you copy pasted what I provided.

Comment: If both object values are of the same type all is fine. The problem only comes up when both types are different, like we got here: a `String` and an `Integer`. I use latest Visual Studio 2019 16.3.0.

Comment: Change to List(Of List(Of Object)) and MyDataSeries.data.Add(New List(Of Object)({"aa", 11})) then.

Comment: Works perfect. Would you copy this to an answer, so every one can see it is solved?

Comment: Don't forget to click the up arrow and checkmark :D